# Google Spreadsheet - Is there a way to overflow over blank cells

Tags: arrays, google-sheets-formula, overflow, vlookup, spreadsheet

I wonder if someone could help me fixing this issue

[image: snapshot of my work]

Planning to have nearly 100 columns to be viewable without scrolling horizontally, so each column shoud have 21 pixels's width, so it's for this reason I can't nor enlarge the columns neither merge themm...

I need that text in A2 overflow/overwrite over E2, F3, G3, H3 cells which are blank since the validation data in E3 is not selected

I want that A2 reacts exactly as I2 is doing by overwrites blank cells in front of it (M2...)

Could you help me fix this out? Any advice would be appreciated.

I share with you an example of my work
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12bmwYSi3exkblW0C2VXqDTq5UGEd5GH8D1PsSkjaFNI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution here is to unmerge A2:

[image]

---

### update:

```
={"";IFNA(VLOOKUP($E$5,Sheet2!$A$2:$E$5,5,FALSE))}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear player0, A2 is already unmerged, but I'm vey surprized by your snapshot!!! Could you please share your copy of your results?

Comment: @Bazu answer updated. see this sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1woWBz_L_X-m_m0-TKI7mH6rjEtTGsEbwwIRQdPh1XkE/edit#gid=1064199597

Comment: you modified E1 instead of E2

Comment: @Bazu yes, thats right. use formulae in row 1 to print stuff in row 2 see A1, E1 and I1 how all of them print stuff in A2, E2 and I2 respectively. this way E2 is truly empty so A2 can roll out through E2 without stopping in D2

Comment: Wow!!!! You made my day dude! I understand your trick, it works properly, then I had just to hide the row 1 and row 3....  and so on... as I made it here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12bmwYSi3exkblW0C2VXqDTq5UGEd5GH8D1PsSkjaFNI/edit?usp=sharing  
Thanks a lot my friend!